# Retrofit2 Throwablecom.google.gsonJsonSyntax expected begin_object but was string at line 2 column 1 path $

Tags: php, android, mysqli, retrofit2, gson

This is the base project for my present undertaking.
The android application runs okay and sends data to the database, however, an error exception is thrown.
The image[A screenshot of my phone's screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/errof.jpg)

The Main Activity

```
package com.mytrendin.retrofitsenddata;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;

import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;

import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    EditText name,email, password;
    Button save;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        name= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
        email= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        password= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save);
        save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
                Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                        .setLenient()
                        .create();

                Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                        .baseUrl("http://192.168.1.4")
                        .client(client)
                        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                        .build();


                ApiService service = retrofit.create(ApiService.class);
                Student student = new Student();
                student.setName(name.getText().toString());
                student.setEmail(email.getText().toString());
                student.setPassword(email.getText().toString());
                Call<Student> call = service.insertData(student.getName(),student.getEmail(),student.getPassword());

                call.enqueue(new Callback<Student>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<Student> call, Response<Student> response) {

                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "response"+response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        name.setText("");
                        email.setText("");
                        password.setText("");

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<Student> call, Throwable t) {


                        Log.i("Hello",""+t);
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Throwable"+t, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }


                });
            }
        });

    }
}
```

The api service class:

```
public interface ApiService {

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/test/index.php")
    Call<Student> insertData(@Field("name") String name, @Field("email") String email , @Field("password") String password);
}
```

The student Class::

```
public class Student {

    String name, email, password;


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

and the PHP server-side script.

```
$username = $_POST['name'];
$useremail = $_POST['email'];
$userpassword = $_POST['password'];
$user = "root";
$pass = "admin@00100";
$host= "localhost";
$dbname="test";

$con = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$dbname);
$sql="insert into userdata(name,email,password) values('".$username."','".$useremail."','".$userpassword."');";
if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
        echo  "data inserted";

}else{  
        echo "Failed";
}
?>
```

The other solutions I've found are not working for the problem at hand. Where could I be going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is actually after insertion your are getting response as a `String` but your are assigning it to `Class Student`

So Replace

```
Call<Student> insertData(@Field("name") String name, @Field("email") String email , @Field("password") String password);
```

with

```
Call<String> insertData(@Field("name") String name, @Field("email") String email , @Field("password") String password);
```

Comment: I'm gettin a "Error:(55, 56) error: incompatible types: Call<String> cannot be converted to Call<Student>" message on the IDE when i make that correction.

Comment: Change <Student> to <String> when u call api